# Smart commit in GIT not working

Tags: git, atlassian-crucible

I have setup Crucible for my GIT repository hosted on Bit Bucket server.
I am making a smart commit as shown below to create a review on Crucible

```
git commit -m "Modified struts core version in pom.xml" +review TP
```

TP is the project code. I am getting the below error :

```
error: pathspec '+review' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'TP' did not match any file(s) know to git
```

Can you help me understand what is causing this error & fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-298976812.html), the review should **part of the comment**.

```
git commit -m "Modified struts core version in pom.xml +review TP"
```

The way you're currently doing it, you're asking the `git` binary to interpret the `+review` command line option, which it does not know how to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried including +review <Project Code> inside commit comments. Though the commit was successful, a review wasn't created in crucible.

Comment: @Karthik, git commits are purely local. I'd be surprised if anything happened until you pushed it to a branch on the server.

Comment: @Karthik, Additionally, it looks like you need to do [some configuration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/enabling-smart-commits-298976933.html) to make things work as well, so you possibly have problems elsewhere also.

Comment: Thanks again for the crucial lead. I just figured out the cause is related to configuration. I am trying find out how to add crucible URL in my GIT configuration file. Please let me know if you know how to add Crucible URL.

Comment: @Karthik, Please accept the answer and ask a new question with details about what you're trying to do.